# Type 'PartialDeep<StringSchema>' is not assignable to type 'Schema<{}>'. TS2345

Tags: typescript, lodash, typescript3.0

I'm getting this error in typescript when using [lodash pick](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#pick) for extracting values of a JSON object.

This is the JSON object:

```
const schema = {
  firstName: yup
   .string()
   .required(REQUIRED_FIELD_MESSAGE)
   .min(1)
   .max(50)
}
```

I have a string[] :

```
list = [
        "firstName"
     ]
```

Then on using pick to fetch only key value pairs from const schema, if I use:

```
pick(schema, list)
```

I get the following error

```
Types of property 'firstName' are incompatible.
    Type 'PartialDeep<StringSchema> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Ref | Schema<{}> | undefined'.
      Type 'PartialDeep<StringSchema>' is not assignable to type 'Ref | Schema<{}> | undefined'.
        Type 'PartialDeep<StringSchema>' is not assignable to type 'Schema<{}>'.  TS2345
```